# What means "Has an inline transform which causes subsequent layers to assume overlap"?

Tags: css, google-chrome, chromium

I'm trying to find the reason for performance problems on a mobile website (based on React and Material UI).

The page shows fairly complex content (a form), which however does not change (in respect to this question). The form itself has `position: fixed`, exact coordinates and even `transform: translateZ(0)`.

Visually on top of the content there is a 48x48 pixel 100% rounded `<div>` (a custom FAB = Floating Action Button) that is scaled up to 25x during a transition (covering the whole screen when finished).

The FAB is basically an overlay for the whole page. It's an element *outside* of the form tree.

When I simplify the page by removing the complex form, the FAB animated smoothly even on low-end hardware (thanks to the GPU).

However, *with* the form the performance decreases significantly.

I see no reason for that and would expect that the form would get it's own layer and only rendered ("painted") once.

When looking at the Chrome DevTools timeline with just the `Paint` option checked I see that a lot of form elements (like a simple label) get re-painted during the animation.

See the images below for the reasons that Chrome gives for that:

[image]

I don't really understand what that means. Why chooses Chrome to repaint these elements?

## Update 1

I was able to reproduce the problem here: http://www.webpackbin.com/N18obvEBM

The problems show up when there is a MUI `<Drawer>`. Even when it is closed (moved out of the viewport using `transform: translate`) it forces the browser to re-render:

[image]

It's even worse if the Drawer is visible on screen.

**Note that apparently it makes a difference if the browser window is on a HiDPI (4K) screen or not.** Same test on a 1050p screen:

[image]

On the lower-res screen the circle is apparently scaled-up from the 48x48px raster rendering (edges become *very* blurry). That does not happen on the HiDPI screen.

Anyway **adding `display:none` to the Drawer layer makes makes the rendering perform well** (but is obviously no solution).

Comment: Can you show some source? Without it, the question is incomplete. It doesn't even mention if the FAB has position:absolute or not.

Comment: I know what you mean. The problem is, this is a complex web app (that I can't show you). [I tried to reproduce it with a testcase](http://www.webpackbin.com/N18obvEBM) but it seems to behave differently. That's why I try to find the reason using the Timeline but after all my question is **What does that `Compositing Reasons` text mean actually?**

Comment: Anyway, I'm happy to explain details. The FAB (which is currently only a rounded <DIV>, just like the testcase) has `position:absolute`, yes

Comment: @MrLister please see my update in the question